# Drop table if exist with similar name in two schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use this command to drop a table in sql-server 2008

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM [DBName]..sysobjects WHERE name = N'TableName' AND xtype='U')
DROP TABLE [DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

But now I have 2 tables with same name in different schema:

```
[DBName].[Schema1].[Members]
```

And

```
 [DBName].[Schema2].[Members]
```

So, what is your suggestion for check if exist this tables? How can I check table names with schema?

**UPDATE:**

OK, there is 3 different answers and all of them worked, so I don't know which one is better, does any one know about use `object_id` or `sys.tables`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM [DBName].sys.tables t
  JOIN [DBName].sys.schemas s
    ON t.SCHEMA_ID = s.schema_id
  WHERE 
      t.name = N'TableName' AND t.type='U' 
  AND s.NAME = 'SchemaName'
)
  DROP TABLE [DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

**Update:**

`object_id` in `sys.tables` is the same as `object_id` in `sysobjects` for the same table. And is completely the same as function OBJECT_ID returns for the same table name. See the following illustrating examples.

So, you may simplify the query:

```
IF exists 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM DBName.sys.tables 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName]')
    AND type = 'U'
  )
  DROP TABLE [DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

or in this way:

```
IF exists 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM DBName.sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName]')
    AND type = 'U'
  )
  DROP TABLE [DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

or for sql2000-styled tables:

```
IF exists 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM DBName..sysobjects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName]')
    AND xtype = 'U'
  )
  DROP TABLE [DBName].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
IF  EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DBName].[Schema1].[Member]') 
    AND type in (N'U')
)
    PRINT 'Yes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'No';
```

Comment: @dotNetist Be careful - due to qualification of object with DB name - it may be run from other DB, so - you need to qualify your `sys.objects` table with DB Name

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sysobjects`. Use the modern [system views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) in the `sys` schema (introduced in 2005):

```
select * from sys.tables
where
    schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('Schema1') and
    name='tablename'
```

As soon as you have one "modern" schema in a 2005 or later database, you *cannot* reliably use `sysobjects` to match with schemas. If you only have "old" schemas (objects belonging to users and roles), you may be able to query based on `user_id`.

Comment: Be careful - due to qualification of object with DB name - it may be run from other DB, where SCHEMA_ID is useless or even bad

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using `sys.tables`, since anything you find in there is, by definition, a table, so no further checks are required on that front.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You should qualify your `sys.tables` with DB name

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simplest just to:

```
IF object_id('[schema].[table]') > 0
    DROP TABLE [schema].[table]
```

For non existent tables `object_id()` returns `NULL`

For some system tables it returns a negative `int`