# How to drop table with the same name in two different schemas with sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

A table was created without specifying the schema in the query. On different databases the table appears in different places. now I need to write a query to remove it in every other database where it was created in the wrong schema (anywhere that is not dbo).
 A simple 'drop table table_name' only seems to remove it in dbo schema. 
The problem is the second schema name may be different in different databases so I can't specify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop table if exist with similar name in two schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451283/drop-table-if-exist-with-similar-name-in-two-schema)

Comment: Checked the question before and didn't quite help

Answer (score 0):

Try this query which is the most common :

```
IF EXISTS(
      SELECT *  FROM [yourdatabase].sys.tables tbl
      JOIN [yourdatabase].sys.schemas ss
        ON tbl.SCHEMA_ID = ss.SCHEMA_ID 
      WHERE 
          tbl.name = N'TableName' AND tbl.type='U' 
      AND ss.NAME = 'SchemaName'
    )
      DROP TABLE [yourdatabase].[SchemaName].[TableName];
```

Comment: thing is the second schema name may be different in different databases depending on users so I can't specify